# Does Hibernate with Jboss make an application slower?

Tags: hibernate, jboss

Is Hibernate with JBoss slow?  Does that overhead cause an application to be slower than say JDBC?  I understand the tradeoffs of object creation and being database agnostic, but in general does Hibernate with JBoss make things slower (slow enough as in say ten seconds faster)?  CRUD.

I have an application that uses the JBoss and Hibernate but it is slow.  If I use something like ODBC and classic (yes, classic) ASP.  Everything comes back lightning fast.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is not slow, it can even be faster than naive JDBC code, but it can be misused.

Answer (score 0):

Misusing Hibernate can be have a deep impact on performance.

I recommend you taking a look at [Hibernate tuning tips](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html) to see if that improves.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to turn the option `hibernate.show_sql` to `true` in your hibernate config and see if there's any unexpected sql generated by hibernate.

In my opinion,one of the common performance overhead is caused by getting the size of a collection as hibernate would try to query the whole collection directly from DB. You may check if there's any similar issue in your program.

As suggested by Gonzalo, you can take a look at the Hibernate tuning tips to see if there's any coding improvement you can done.